# CSS keeping getting pushed down

Tags: css, class, html

http://bit.ly/oSJwP2

Anyone know how to fix my `#updates` or give me some hints?
I've tried to give them positions, but it keeps getting messed up.
Thanks.

EDIT: `.chatango` is now messed up. in IE, anyone?
Thanks.

Comment: Switch the order so that the element of class `chatango` is last in the #content_inner element. And float left to #updates element.

Comment: Sorry, I'm running Linux. No IE availability.

Comment: @Layke Alright, if you have any idea please tell. Basically the same problem just with the other side now `chatango`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float: left;` to `#updates`. That seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: I already tried it though, look now. I updated it with `float: left;` I am on chrome btw.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. I had to decrease my width. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: The problem still remains in IE, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It's looking fine in IE now. What's the issue exactly?

Comment: The right side is pushed down to the bottom.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that your widths were exceeding capacity and you should have both elements floated left. There are several css steps you can make to get this to work. I tested on firefox and ie in compatibility mode and it works fine. First remove the width from `#content`. Then have `#content_inner` set to `float: left;` and remove width as well. Finally set `#chatango` to `float: left;` and remove `left: 630px;` That should do it. I tested this out with debugger tools so it might not be 100% correct but try it out.

Comment: Beautiful! Works just as I wanted it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The best I can do is to provide a generic solution, since I can't check in IE.

Things to generally look out for.

- Make sure that the parent container has a width and that this width is at least larger than the children elements.
- If you are floating the elements, I would do the float left first, and then float:right
- If you are having problems with IE, beaware of margin and indentation [bugs](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html).

If you can, you might want to consider using a "grid system".

For example...

Make your container 900px, then if you have two child elements, you can set widths on them, and then give then `float:left` on both, or `display:inline-block` (preferable).

Comment: Thanks Layke, I'll go trough your checks.